# From JavaScript to Objective-C with JSON

Tags: javascript, objective-c, json

I have no idea how to properly 'return' this JSON object (in JavaScript):

```
function callback() {   
                var points = '{\"points\": [';
                var params = polyline.getLatLngs();

                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    params = params.concat('{\"latitude\": ', points[i].lat, ', \"longitude\": ', points[i].lng, '}');
                    if (i < points.length - 1) {
                        params = params.concat(', ');
                    }
                }
                params = params.concat('] }');

                return JSON.parse(params);
            }
```

I want to catch it with something like (Objective-C):

```
NSString *s = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"callback();"];
```

Obviously this results in a NSString, what I really want is NSData to do this (Objective-C):

```
NSData *data = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

So, how to properly return the JSON?

Comment: I'm sorry, did you just construct a JavaScript object in JavaScript by concatenation, then parse it?

Comment: What @minitech means is that JavaScript **natively** understands JSON syntax - you don't have to construct a string like that and parse it; you can just create the object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function callback() {
    var params = polyline.getLatLngs();
    var result = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        result.push({latitute: params[i].lat, longitude: params[i].long});
    }

    return JSON.stringify({points: result});
}
```

Note that `JSON.parse` generates an object from a string, and `JSON.stringify` creates a string from an object. No need to do it manually.